# Nested Dictionary Data Extraction

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples

I have a dictionary made up of multiple other dictionaries.  These other dictionaries are identical in structure.  They are made up of an integer, two strings, and a list.  The lists are made up of multiple tuples.  All tuples are made up of a string followed by an integer.  I would like to extract all the integers in the tuples in all dictionaries.  An example of the dictionary would be this:

```
mast_dict = {"cap_1": {"id":1001, "unit":"unit1", "area":"Portland", "vitals":[("HR", 60), ("RR", 12), 
("temp", 102)]}, "cap_2":{"id":1002, "unit":"unit2", "area":"Moscow", "vitals":[("HR", 54), ("RR", 15),
("temp", 101)]}}
```

I am having a lot of difficulty extracting the elements from the tuples.  The closest post I found to this was more about running a for loop, but did not seem to include this many layers.  I would like to be able to do this over many more dictionaries within the mast_dict dictionary.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list comp:

```
numbers = [tup[1] for d in mast_dict.values() for tup in d['vitals']]

>>> numbers

[60, 12, 102, 54, 15, 101]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly.  The syntax of calling some of the different types of data in Python is proving tricky for me to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference e.g "HR" in "cap_1" by running this line of code:

```
mast_dict['cap_1']['area'][0][0]
```

that will return "HR"